# ngHandsontable scientific notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I am using ngHandsOnTable in my application primarily for its features of copy/paste from excel.

Now, the issue is with scientific notation values . When I try to copy the value from excel like `3.39E+40(3.3900123456789E+40)` and paste it in ngHandsontable, the resulted value is quite different what is being copied from excel. In this case the value being paste is `3.39000000000E+40`. I have no clue why the numbers have been rounded off or truncated.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved here:
[GitHub Rep](https://github.com/IvanReznikov/hotScience)

```
    //Test:
    //1e+3
    //2E-2
    //-1.2e-1
    //3,411E+4
    //-0e-3
    //0.211E+3
    //0,99E1.1
    //3.01E0,5
```